how do I fix error installing phytools in r
Help please, using R in R-studio and package phytools won't install non-zero exit status no package called igraph, complete error message below. I'm using R 4.2.1 on Mac os 10.15.7 [Catalina]
install.packages("phytools")


There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
binary source needs_compilation phytools  2.0-3  2.1-1             FALSE
installing the source package ‘phytools’
trying URL
'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/phytools_2.1-1.tar.gz' Content
type 'application/x-gzip' length 483368 bytes (472 KB)
================================================== downloaded 472 KB

installing source package ‘phytools’ ...
** package ‘phytools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
vI[[j]]) :    there is no package called ‘igraph’ Calls: 
... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart ->
doWithOneRestart Execution halted ERROR: lazy loading failed for
package ‘phytools’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/phytools’
Warning in install.packages :   installation of package ‘phytools’ had
non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/0p/3t967vdj5912d6tyymzmc1602rg94r/T/RtmppbVTfa/downloaded_packages’
tried installing package, tried to check compatibility of versions.
phytools 2.1 says requires R >= 3.5


Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should try install.packages('igraph', dependencies = TRUE), or look at igraph, install all imports (and possibly suggests), then return to phytools install. dependencies = TRUE) is your useful friend..

Thanks, this got me on the right track. I was able to install igraph separately as you suggested (although it only worked with the already compiled version), and then once it was installed I was able to install phytools but with dependencies = FALSE so that it did not try (and fail) to reinstall igraph. Thanks again

It wouldn't re-install something that was present on the search path of packages that fulfilled version requirements. The dependencies = TRUE was just a general comment. I'll also library(help = 'some_package') to clarify if a depencency is already installed prior . Glad it worked.
